# Appending data to existing tables in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Im trying to append some data to an existing table in an excel spreadsheet using openpyxl

All i could find in the docs were how to create a new table and not about how to add data to them

Any help or workaround to this would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Specifically [playing with data](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#playing-with-data), and [Inserting and deleting rows and columns](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html#inserting-and-deleting-rows-and-columns-moving-ranges-of-cells). Another useful method is [`append`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append)

Comment: I did and as i mentioned before they talk about adding data to the worksheet and not to a specific table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the worksheets _tables. Let's say that your table is named *SalesTable* and you want to edit the tables range to A1:C10. Set the `table.ref` to "A1:C10"

```
for table in worksheet._tables:
    if table.displayName == "SalesTable":
        table.ref = "A1:C10"
```

With newer versions of OpenPyXL `_tables` has changed to `.tables`

```
for table in worksheet.tables:
    if table.displayName == "SalesTable":
        table.ref = "A1:C10"
```